# Difficulty inserting an image into a PDF while using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xml-parsing, itext

I referenced [this blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66948/Rendering-PDF-views-in-ASP-MVC-using-iTextSharp) when setting up a way to dynamically generate PDFs for my MVC3 application.

I got everything working fine until I wanted to add an image to the PDF.

Here is my exact view that functions properly without an image:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Student

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<itext creationdate="2/4/2013 5:49:07 PM" producer="iTextSharpXML">
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="16.0" align="Center">
        <chunk>Orders in PDF</chunk>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="10.0" align="Center">
        <chunk>First Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName) </chunk><newline />
        <chunk>Last Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</chunk><newline />
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="10.0" align="Default">
    <chunk font="unknown" size="12.0">Orders:</chunk><newline />
    </paragraph>
</itext>
```

Here is what I am attempting to use to include an image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<itext creationdate="2/4/2013 5:49:07 PM" producer="iTextSharpXML">
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="16.0" align="Default">
        <chunk>Orders in PDF</chunk>
        <image url="/Content/images/myImage.jpg" plainwidth="194.0" plainheight="202.0" />
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="10.0" align="Default">
        <chunk>First Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName) </chunk><newline />
        <chunk>Last Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</chunk><newline />
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="10.0" align="Default">
    <chunk font="unknown" size="12.0">Orders:</chunk><newline />
    </paragraph>
</itext>
```

When trying to generate the PDF with the image, I get an `Exception Occurred` error when the app is trying to parse ( `textHandler.Parse(xmldoc);` ) the xml to generate the pdf.  The error's inner-exception states: `"The network path was not found.\r\n"`.  I assume I am having this problem because I have no idea how I should be including an image into this iTextSharpXML page and am unable to find proper documentation on how to do so.

I just want to center an image at the top of the PDF - how should I go about formatting this properly?

**Update**

If I change my 'image' tag to look like this:

```
<paragraph leading="18.0" font="unknown" size="16.0" align="Center">
    <chunk>Orders in PDF</chunk>
    <img src="/Content/images/myImage.jpg" />
</paragraph>
```

I can generate the PDF, but no image appears - no error, but it looks the same as the first pdf without the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the absolute url to image tag

```
<image url="http://myserver/Content/images/myImage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i was able to see an image using this code set up:

```
<image url="@Context.Server.MapPath("/Content/images/myImage.jpg")" />
```